# Vtiger + Xampp not working on other LAN systems (Working on Server/localhost)

Tags: xampp, crm, vtiger

**My objective:** Install & implement Vtiger (any version) with XAMPP/WAMP (does not matter) on the small & simple LAN (4 PC)

**Local Area Network:** 4 Desktops (win 7) + Broadband router

**Progress so far:** Successfully installed Vtiger 6.5.0 + XAMPP PHP 5.6.31 on one of the 4 desktops(192.168.1.10). Its working absolutely fine on the desktop (192.168.1.10). But (192.168.1.10/vtigercrm) not opening on other 3 desktops. (192.168.1.10/dashboard) is opening fine on other 3 desktops. I'm able to open 192.168.1.10/vtigercrm (installation wizard) on other 3 desktops after extracting "vtigercrm6.5.0" to "htdocs". But, as soon as the installation is done; it stops loading the page (err_connection_refused)

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Might be in config.inc.php file your $site_URL will be http://localhost/vtigercrm instead of IP address of your desktop. Replace localhost with your IP address.

Answer (score -1):

In the `vtigercrm` folder look for `config.inc.php` change

`$site_URL = 'http://localhost/vtigercrm/';` for your static localhost

```
$site_URL = 'http://172.16.1.116/vtigercrm/';
```